# Usages of <ul> for formatting

Tags: html, css, layout, position, html-lists

I tend to use `<li>` all the time to format and position text. It's works, I just don't want to be creating a website the wrong way. I'm new to this and I want to learn the proper ways.

*Am I using unordered lists the right way?*

Answer (score 1):

CSS should be used to format and position text and elements. Unordered lists (`<ul>`) are for semantics only; the same is true for any HTML element. Also, while browsers do apply default formatting and styling for certain elements, these browser-specific default styles shouldn't be heavily relied on.

Use `<ul>` and/or `<ol>` because you want to display a list or lists, don't use it because browsers apply automatic indentation.

Comment: This is what ive done so far http://i.imgur.com/6mzvC.png . I used <ul> for the navigation bar, and the text (buttons) under the image slider. Was that misuse of <ul>?

Comment: @Jshulman Nope. Those are actually examples of proper use. The navigation is definitely always considered a list, and the text under the slider is a list of services. I was operating under the assumption that you used it for the entirety of your layout. Now that I see a working example, kudos :]

Answer (score 0):

A list is a list. If your whole website consists of list-content's, than you should use lists. But if not you should remember, that HTML has a lot more tags than just `UL` and `LI`. Choose those tags that match the semantic meaning of the content. For example a `P` for text paragraphs or even the new HTML5 tags like `ARTICLE` to enclose a whole post.

Beside real list contents, like staff members on a company website, I use lists primarly in two cases: A) as navigation menus and B) to format forms (where each `LI` is a form row, containing a `LABEL` and some input).

Comment: What feeela said. I would advise against the use of the newer HTML5 tags, but that's for other reasons not related to this post. Anyway, +1

Comment: So how should i have set up the site im working on? This is what i've done: http://i.imgur.com/6mzvC.png . It layed  out mostly by <ul> formatted inline using css. I understand to use <p> for text but that doesn't help position multiple pieces of text thats why ive been using <ul> and within that <p>. Heres a portion of what i did: http://i.imgur.com/k3FX8.png http://i.imgur.com/i74Kp.png

Comment: You can apply styles to `<p>`, such as padding and margin, just as you could with `<li>`.